# Use options with node's scoped http client, set rejectUnauthorized to false

Tags: node.js, https, coffeescript

With node's HTTP library I can easily set the options I want

```
options = 
  port: 443 
  path: "/"
  method: 'GET'
  rejectUnauthorized: false

https.get options, (res) -> 
  ...
```

How do I do the same thing with node-scoped-http-client?

```
# Passing options doesn't seem to work (defined as above)
cli = msg.http(stats_url, options)

# Injecting it doesn't pass it on either
cli.options['rejectUnauthorized'] = false
```

I'm still getting this error: `ERROR Error: UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE`

Am I missing something else here? I'm fairly new to node and coffeescript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short Answer:

You can't. Currently, scoped-http-client only [passes on certain options](https://github.com/technoweenie/node-scoped-http-client/blob/master/src/index.coffee#L29-L36) to `http` or `https`:

```
   req = (if @options.protocol == 'https:' then https else http).request(
    port:    port
    host:    @options.hostname
    method:  method
    path:    @fullPath()
    headers: headers
    agent:   @options.agent or false
  )
```

Long Answer:

Add it to your own fork, send a pull request. The cheap way would be to add it directly to the above request call. The better way to handle it is to actually use the options object passed in upon creation of the client.

Comment: I believe the lib has been updated to pass through all but a subset of options, see [source](https://github.com/technoweenie/node-scoped-http-client/blob/master/src/index.coffee)

Answer (score 0):

rejectUnauthorized should be a property on the agent. Try something like this...

```
options.agent = new https.Agent(options);
```